# How can i divide the data and put inside textboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a page to create emails structures, and edit.

To do the edit, i inserted two columns in my page, and one of them, got the information from all the columns and two buttons, one to edit, and another one to remove.

when the user clicks at edit, all the information from the clicked email structure, goes to a second column, and the values are inserted into an textarea, a textbox for the title, and a hidden input for the ID.

I did that using Ajax

```
function func(element){
var templateId = $(element).val();

          $.ajax({ 

              type: "POST", 

              url: "/private/admin/modules/ajax/controller/ajax.php",

              data : {

                            'module': 'forms',
                            'option': 'send',
                            'function': 'changeTextArea',
                            'temp_id': templateId,
                            'ax': 1

              },

              success: function(data){ 

nicEditors.findEditor( "area2" ).setContent(data);
$('.test2').val(templateTitle);
            }

        });
}
```

The templateId comes from this button:

```
<button onclick="func(this);" value="'.$val['template_id'].'" name="edit" value="">Edit</button>
```

This is the function that i made to get the values from the specific email structure

```
function changeTextArea($template_id){

   $templates = ("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE template_id = ".$template_id." ");  

   $template= db_query($templates, 'r');

 $text = $template['text'];
 $title = $template['name'];
 $id = $template['template_id'];

    print_manage($text, $title, $id);

}
```

And i'm printing all the stuff here, in this function, those informations are supposed to be inserted into the textbox, the input hidden, and the textarea

```
function print_manage($text, $title, $id){

echo $text; //textarea

echo $title; //textbox

echo $id; //input hidden

}
```

Now my question is, how can i divide those values.

because i'm receiving everything in line, like this:

text - name - id

i want to distribute all the values like this:

textbox - Title

Hidden input - ID

Textarea - Text

I heard about Json, but i dont know how to do it, can somebody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for transfering data between server and client

```
function changeTextArea($template_id) {
    $templates = ("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE template_id = ".$template_id." ");  
    $template = db_query($templates, 'r');
    echo json_encode($template);
}
```